# Error from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

When I install Android Studio 3.0.1 I have error like this:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download junit.jar
>   (junit:junit:4.12)
>
> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
> >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 269; received: 0

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your application/project ->

open module settings->

Go to "Dependencies" tab ->

you'll find "junit:junit:4.12" ->

select it and right click and choose remove option -> ok